# Mongo failed to start

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am running a mean app, but when I go to run 'mongo', I get the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-25T02:15:24.329-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to 
server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error 
connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I am sure I am missing something simple here.

Comment: try with `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: Can you show your code snippet? How are you connecting to db.?

Answer (score 0):

**mongo** is the Mongo shell. It connects to the Mongo daemon, **mongod**, which isn't running - hence the error.

At the command-line: sudo mongod

Enter your password, and the daemon should start. Now, when you run **mongo** it should start up ok.

Comment: I ran that, but when I go to run 'npm start' on my MEAN app, I get this:

Comment: Server started on port 8080
Database error MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds12226.mlab.com:12226] on first connect [MongoError: g
etaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ds12226.mlab.com ds12226.mlab.com:12226]